# Maven doesn't build project whereas IDE does

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pom.xml

I have project, where I use diamond operators, thus I need to use SDK 1.7. In my ItelliJ IDEA, I've set in project properties, that SDK 1.7 should be used and I can make the project without any problem. Nevertheless when I want to build the project via console 'mvn clean install' I get this message and the build fails:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.
5.1:compile (default-compile) on project myproject-war: Compilation failure: Comp
ilation failure:
[ERROR] C:\Users\Martin\Documents\GitHub\MyProject\myproject-war\src\main\java\net
\myproject\myproject\serviceLayer\serviceImpl\GenericServiceImpl.java:[64,40] erro
r: diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR] (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
```

in the project and parent `pom.xml` is clearly defined which java version should be used 
`<java-version>1.7</java-version>`

Is there some way, how to force `maven` to use the right java version?

Comment: Type `java -version` on the console: the path on your console does not have java 7 at the front.

Comment: it does `java version "1.7.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)`

Comment: ah...solution found in the duplicated question :)

Comment: ok, sorry, then see the faq referenced in the duplicate where the maven-compiler-plugin is explicitly over-ridden in the pom.